# What does it mean when a class style is greyed out in Chrome's style inspector?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Why is the following class (.productQuote) greyed out in the inspector? I can't edit it.

[image: image showing class in Chrome greyed out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the currently selected DOM node, this pane displays all the styles
>   applicable to this node. Styles with gray background are read-only,
>   the rest are editable.

**Source:** [Computed Style Pane](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles)

Usually the grayed out areas are for `user agent stylesheet` styles, which are styles defined by the browser vendor. These are typically overridden by your own styles. You can use [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to normalize the styles across browsers.

I am not totally sure why `.productQuote` is specifically grayed out here, but my guess is it's come from a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Greyed/dimmed out text, is because your currently selected element is inheriting a style property which was applied to an ancestor element.
i.e. the `.productQuote` class is applying a CSS property, (possibly the `background-color`) to a parent element, that property has being inherited  by your currently selected element.
So its a user-defined style, but because its not applied directly, its greyed out.

Comment: Ah so if I look at all the parent classes in the HTML, eventually I'll be able to edit it.

Comment: yes, try checking to see if any of the parent classes contain something like `class="productQuote"` or apply a CSS property directly to the element you are inspecting so that its own style just overrides the inherited one.

Comment: I've actually solved it now. The style sheet had edits in Visual Studio, which seems to lock the inspector from editing it, but thanks for your help.